# Pip virtualenv do not correlate, Error: "Unable to find a suitable output format for ..."

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

In an attempt to manually install a package, I accidentally copied a file (ffmpeg) over the pip that I was using on that particular virtualenv.

As a result I can't use pip anymore. How can I reinstall pip on my virtualenv, or how can I use pip3 to correlate to the python in the virtualenv?

Previously when I said 'which pip' it would say:

```
/Users/tax/.virtualenv/capstone/bin/pip", but now it gives the error: "Unable to find a suitable output format for '/Users/tax/.virtualenvs/capstone/bin/pip'
/Users/tax/.virtualenvs/capstone/bin/pip: Invalid argument
```

Does anyone have a clue how to fix this? It would be a real pain if I had to make a new virtualenv.

Comment: What exactly did you do? Did you rewrite your pip executable with a different file?

Comment: I did cp _path_/ffmpeg _path_/pip. So i copied the content of ffmpeg into pip i think, because when i called pip it gave me an error about ffmpeg, so i think yes to your question if i understand it correctly.

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you accidentally rewrote your pip executable, just create a new virtualenv the same way you created your current one and copy the new pip executable to your old virtualenv (thus rewriting the corrupted one).